# How to provide private s3 bucket credentials to electron-updater

Tags: electron, electron-builder, electron-updater

I am able to implement electron-updater in my electron app with a public s3 bucket.  But the same doesn't work with a private bucket.  I am getting

`Error: HttpError: 403 Forbidden`

I assume the application does not have AWS accesskey and secretkey required to access the private s3 bucket.  How to instruct electron-updater to use credentials during `autoUpdater.checkForUpdates()` and `autoUpdater.downloadUpdate()`

Comment: Any credentials you include in your application should be considered as good as compromised.

Answer (score 0):

How about this steps?

1. make signedUrl used by aws-sdk
2. bind signedUrl to setFeedURL

If you do this step, you may check about aws signature version.